# Windows 8 64 bit not recognizing my 3 screens resolutions correctly.

Tags: multiple-monitors, resolution, eyefinity

Hi I recently purchased 3 asus 29" widescreen IPS monitors each has a resolution of 2560x1080p. I have to sapphire 7970 6gb gpus in crossfire and when I hook the 3 up using 2 dvi cords and 1 active mini display-port to dvi adapter 2 screens max out at 1920x1080p and the center one is at the correct 2560x1080p. I am trying to use all 3 in eyefinity which should be 7860x1080p but when activated max is 3120xx1020p or something weird like that. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to use dual-link DVI cables for resolutions this high - it sounds like you might have single-link (which cap out at around 1200p).